# What can be said about the image of this kind of map?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that we have $f(x), g(x)$ and $h(x)$ all from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ so that, say, $f$ and $g$ are convex and $h$ is concave. (or any combination of the sort). In my case, $f$, $g$, and $h$ each have gradients which are always parallel to vectors $u$,$v$,and $w$ respectively, and $u$, $v$, and $w$ are pairwise independent. In other words, each of $f,g,$ and $h$ are of the form $\phi(c_1 x + c_2 y)$ where $\phi$ is either concave or convex.

What sorts of things can be said about the image of the map $(f,g,h)$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$? For example, can a $2$-plane only intersect this image in one connected component?

I know very little differential geometry (this is related to a project I'm working on), so as an answer I'd also be happy with reference to a chapter of a textbook that I can work towards as well.

Comment: I would suggest you try lots of examples. You also need some hypotheses to make sure you even locally get a (smooth) surface for the image.

Comment: What hypotheses are needed to make it smooth? I suppose I can say that f,g, and h always have nonzero derivative and for each of these maps there is a vector u along which d_u is always positive for each point in R^2.

Comment: Do you know basic multivariable analysis? You need the mapping to have rank $2$ at every point. This guarantees local smoothness.

Comment: I've taken it, but it's been a while. In that case, I have no concern about smoothness; the vectors u I mentioned are linearly independent. I was worried I had neglected something basic!

Comment: I don't know what this means. But what if $f=g$, for example?

Comment: I see -- I'd be in danger of getting a lower dimensional image. I suppose that what I meant by the vectors u is that each map's gradient is always parallel to the same vector (That is, f's gradient is always parallel to $u$ everywhere, $g$'s gradient is always parallel to $v$, and $h$'s gradient is always parallel to $w$, and $u,v,w$ are linearly independent).

Comment: Well, you can't have three linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^2$. And the gradients of $f$, $g$, and $h$ change direction from point to point, so things are sloppy here.

Comment: Gah, I'm tired. Sorry. They are pairwise independent. And what I'm saying is that in my case the gradients of $f$, $g$, and $h$ do not change direction though they do change magnitude.

Comment: Really? They don't change direction? That's a very restrictive condition. That seems to say that each of your functions is a function of the form $\phi(c_1x+c_2y)$ for some constants $c_1,c_2$.

Comment: Yes, that is the case. And each $\phi$ is either concave or convex.

Comment: So please edit your question to make all your hypotheses crystal-clear. You certainly never said that $f$, $g$, and $h$ were all built in this way from functions of a single variable.

Comment: Is my edit clearer now?